# React-Native App with a Apple Watch App

Tags: ios, json, react-native, apple-watch

I have a react-native based question, we are building a react-native application that will use authentication to call a secured API for data.

This is all built in react-native, however I am wanting to build a Apple Watch app (I know react-native doesn't and won't likely soon support this) So I am planning to go native swift for the Watch App.

My question is, does anyone know if you can use the react-native based authentication and api mapping to supply a json object to the Watch App? I want to simply display a json schedule on the watch from the phone.

Comment: Did you find a solution on how to accomplish this?